# Carousel which gives Preview of html files

Tags: html, ios, xcode, swift, uiwebview

I am writing my first `Swift` iOS app in which I have a list of html files to be loaded on `UIWebView` I need to have a horizontal slider to preview all the html files(number of files vary depending on the file that has been selected) at the bottom on the UI. I have searched but was unable to get satisfactory response for the same.

I plan to load to load horizontally carousel of  `UIWebView` which will load html file on `UIWebView` and would be of relative small size of that the user can have feel of preview

Please   guide me in how to achieve this task by following best/optimized iOS development practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could definitely take a look at these pods :

- **[iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel)**
- **[MVCarouselCollectionView](https://github.com/bizz84/MVCarouselCollectionView)**
- **[SwiftCarousel](https://github.com/DroidsOnRoids/SwiftCarousel)**

I would go with the swift Carousel. Maybe not the most powerful but it seems that it will fit your needs.

- You could define your model (what will your carousel show ?)
- Use Alamofire/SwiftyJSON to handle web calls and safely populate your data
- Use this pod to handle the display with the power and flexibility of collectionviews

Good luck !